# Error "use of unassigned local variable" when using do while loop and bool variable in c#

Tags: c#

I have a problem which I mentioned in the title, just need some help to get rip of this annoying error.

Here's my code:

```
bool moreEmp;
int arrayplus;
string doitagain;
arrayplus = -1;

string[,] employees = new string[10, 10];

do
{
    arrayplus++;
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your employee's number");
    employees[0, arrayplus] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your employee's name");
    employees[1, arrayplus] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your employee's age");
    employees[2, arrayplus] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your employee's official position ");
    employees[3, arrayplus] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("please enter your employee's salary");
    employees[4, arrayplus] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to add more employees into this list? y or n.");

    doitagain = Console.ReadLine();

    if (doitagain == "y" || doitagain == "Y")
    {
       moreEmp = true;
    }
    else if (doitagain == "n" || doitagain == "N")
    {
       moreEmp = false;
    }
    else
    {
       Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid information");
    }
} 
while (moreEmp == true);
```

So I actually assigned bool variable with my if statement, I still don't know why I made such a error like this. Thank for reading my question and hopefully you will help me out :D.

Comment: You shouldn't be using a 2D array to store this information.  Instead create an `Employee` class with a `Name`, `Salary`, `Age`, etc. values.  Then make a `List<Employee>` to store this information.  By creating a named class you'll now know exactly what each of those values means, you won't need to remember which array position holds which value.  A List is also better than an array, since you don't know how many you'll need when you start, and a List will dynamically resize itself as you add items, unlike an array.

Comment: Instead of doitagain = Console.ReadLine();
            if (doitagain == "y" || doitagain == "Y"), use doitagain = Console.ReadLine().ToLower and check against "y" and "n" only.

Comment: @NWard The use of `ToLower` to do a case intensive compare is generally a bad practice, in general.  1) It doesn't work well in non-English languages (see the Turkey Test). 2) It's more performance intensive (obviously not an issue here, but in general it can be) 3) it doesn't semantically state what you're trying to do correctly.  Instead use a string comparer that's case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You assign a value in the `if`, and the `else if`, but not in the `else` clause.  If that final `else` is hit, the value is never assign to that variable.

Looking at your code, it should probably be assigned a `true` value in that `else`.  That will fix the problem for you.

Comment: Well.Thanks you,it help a lot,i just try to fix my problem by add a value when i declare my varriable(bool moreEmp = false),but it more like a trick to get rip of the error than actually solve the problem.After reading your post i can finally understand the problem :D.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in `else` block, how do you handle when `doitagain` is neither `n/N` or `y/Y`.

So either use this

```
else
{
    moreEmp = false; //Set this as your requirement
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered an invalid information");
}
```

Or

```
bool moreEmp = false;
do{
    if (doitagain == "y" || doitagain == "Y")
    {
        moreEmp = true;
    }
}while(moreEmp);
```